# Can't normalize nested Json in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am desperately trying to normalize this pandas column, which contains a json structure.

```
ENTRID           PAYLOAD
486473  "{""ratingInformation"":{""rating"": 5.0, ""rating_raw"": 5.0, ""numberOfRating"": 9}, ""serviceFeatures"":{""delivery"": true, ""amenities"": [{""Akzeptierte Karten"": ""Kredit, EC"", ""Lieferung möglich"": ""Ja"", ""Parkplatz & Parkhaus"": ""Kundenparkplatz""}]}, ""starRatings"": {""numOneStarRatings"":0,""numTwoStarRatings"":0,""numThreeStarRatings"":0,""numFourStarRatings"":1,""numFiveStarRatings"":8}}"
76975   "{""ratingInformation"":{""rating"": 5.0, ""rating_raw"": 5.0, ""numberOfRating"": 9}, ""serviceFeatures"":{""amenities"": [{""Reservierung möglich"": ""Kein Lieferservice""}]}, ""starRatings"": {""numOneStarRatings"":0,""numTwoStarRatings"":0,""numThreeStarRatings"":0,""numFourStarRatings"":1,""numFiveStarRatings"":8}}"
```

My Code looks like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('MatchingEID_reduced.csv', sep=';', encoding = 'utf-8')
json_struct = json.loads(df.to_json(orient="records"))
df_flat = pd.json_normalize(json_struct)
```

*Problem:*
My result is the same structure as before. -> The two columns named *`'ENTRID'`* and *`'PAYLOAD'`*

Any ideas how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that *PAYLOAD* is *JSON* before you try to normalize it.

```
import json
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""ENTRID           PAYLOAD
486473  "{""ratingInformation"":{""rating"": 5.0, ""rating_raw"": 5.0, ""numberOfRating"": 9}, ""serviceFeatures"":{""delivery"": true, ""amenities"": [{""Akzeptierte Karten"": ""Kredit, EC"", ""Lieferung möglich"": ""Ja"", ""Parkplatz & Parkhaus"": ""Kundenparkplatz""}]}, ""starRatings"": {""numOneStarRatings"":0,""numTwoStarRatings"":0,""numThreeStarRatings"":0,""numFourStarRatings"":1,""numFiveStarRatings"":8}}"
76975   "{""ratingInformation"":{""rating"": 5.0, ""rating_raw"": 5.0, ""numberOfRating"": 9}, ""serviceFeatures"":{""amenities"": [{""Reservierung möglich"": ""Kein Lieferservice""}]}, ""starRatings"": {""numOneStarRatings"":0,""numTwoStarRatings"":0,""numThreeStarRatings"":0,""numFourStarRatings"":1,""numFiveStarRatings"":8}}"
"""), sep="\s+")
pd.json_normalize(df
                  .assign(PAYLOAD=lambda dfa: dfa["PAYLOAD"].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x)))
                  .to_dict(orient="records")
                 )
```

Comment: Oh nice idea. However I have not thought of this way. Thank you. Works well! SOLVED